# R's try() does not catch errors produced by file.remove()

Tags: r, try-catch

I am trying to catch an error thrown by `file.remove()`, when for example an Excel file is opened and therefore cannot be removed. 
It seems that R's `try()` function doesn't work in this case. The following code still produces an error to the console although argument `silent` is set to `TRUE` and nothing is stored to the variable:

```
removal.error <- try(file.remove("testfile.xlsx"), silent = T)
```

> removal.error
>   [1] FALSE

Any suggestions why this is the case or workarounds to catch such an error?

Comment: What about `tryCatch`? You can return the message in case of error or warning, etc

Comment: Please read the help for `file.remove` and look in the Value section. ASFAICS both `file.remove` and `try` are working as expected and described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nor the `try` or `tryCatch` functions are catching any error because the `remove.file` function is working properly (as said by @Bhas) and it throws a `FALSE` value that could be used to handle the error as shown below:

```
write.csv2(x = data.frame(V1 = 1:10, V2 = letters[1:10]),
           file = 'file.csv')

shell('start excel file.csv') # opens excel to throw the error

rem <- try(file.remove('file.csv'))
rem # [1] FALSE

if (rem == FALSE) {
  shell('taskkill /F /IM excel.exe') # handle the error you pointed us
  rem_2 <- file.remove('file.csv')
  if(rem_2 == FALSE) { # if this was not the case, warn the user
    warning(warnings())
    class(rem) <- c(class(rem), "try-error") # and add try-error class to 'rem'
  }
}
```

After that, you'll be able to handle this as you've planned.

OBS: run this code line by line, otherwise `R` is going to be faster than excel and you're not going to see any error in the console.